# Linux и DNS: This site can’t be reached ... DNS address could not be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, dns, xubuntu

После переезда в другой город и подключения там к сети, у меня стали отваливаться практически все сайты с указанной ошибкой. Например, при доступе к `xubuntu.org`:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> xubuntu.org’s server DNS address could not be found.
>
> Try:
>   Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

[image: This site can’t be reached ...]

Я попробовал, что перечислено под `Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration`, но ничего не помогло.

Как я понял, проблема с DNS-серверами ... Провайдер ByFly (Беларусь) и для каждой области есть [свои](http://hpc.by/dns_byfly) DNS-сервера, ну или можно взять сервера от Google или Yandex.

Я взял от Google и добавил его в `Network Settings - DNS`:

[image: Xubuntu Network Settings - DNS]

Вроде всё заработало, но проблемы остались (по крайней мере с какими я столкнулся):

- после перезагрузки добавленый IP-адрес DNS-сервера (`8.8.8.8`) исчезает;
- при доступе с помощью Git к Bitbucket вылетает ошибка `Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable`.

Раньше был на Ubuntu и не наблюдал такого поведения: то есть при перездах ничего не «нарушалось» — всё работало исправно.

Отчего может возникать данная проблема и как с ней бороться?

---

**OC**: Xubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, отключив IPv6, всё заработало без лишних манипуляций.

**P. S.** Также работает и при значении не `Ignore`, а `Automatic, DHCP only`.

---

[image: Xubuntu Network Connections]

[image: Xubuntu Network Connections - Editing - IPv6 Settings]